# Trouble with Converting to Datetime Type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a Pandas dataframe similar to the following:

```
valid               Measurement  Room
2014-02-03 12:48    0.50         23
2014-02-03 12:53    0.43         23
2014-02-03 12:59    0.21         23
2014-02-03 13:06    0.23         23
2014-02-03 13:13    0.10         23
...
```

I am trying to read in these dates. They are currently strings, but I want to read them as `date time`; however, that isn't working out so well.

```
def hourlyDataSet(fp):
  df = pd.read_csv(fp)#data frame
  df[['day', 'time']] = df['valid'].str.split().apply(pd.Series)
  mat='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
  df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format = mat)
  newdf =  df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "datetime",freq= "H")).sum()
  return df
```

Using the above function, I am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: time data '12:48' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M' (match)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you split `'valid'`, then `mat` does not match the format of `'time'`
- The function should be as follows

```py
def hourlyDataSet(fp):

    # read the data file
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)

    # convert the valid column, to a datetime format
    df['valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    # use .Grouper on the datetime column
    newdf =  df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="valid", freq="H")).sum()

    return newdf
```